# Rspec/Capybara "feature" method undefined when Guard runs specs in watched files, works when run manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, rspec, capybara, guard

I am getting a strange issue when using Guard to run my specs.

I am running a feature spec that uses the Capybara "feature" / "scenario" syntax. I am also using Spring.

Everything works fine if I run `rspec spec` or `spring rspec` in the console or `rspec` in the Guard shell. But, when the watched specs get run automatically by Guard, I get the following error:

> /spec/features/navigation_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`feature' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Why is it not picking up the Capybara syntax only in this specific context?

Here is the relevant code:

GuardFile

```
guard :rspec, :spring => true do
    watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
end
```

spec/features/navigation_spec.rb

```
feature "navigation" do
    context "When on the home page" do
        before { visit "/" }

        scenario "I should see the navigation header" do
            expect(page).to have_selector("div.navigation")
        end
    end
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run just this one spec from those other contexts? I'm wondering if it's the absence of `require 'spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: You are on to something. If I just run the one spec from the command line I get the same error. So what is the issue? It's still not completely clear to me.

Comment: Nevermind. Got it. Forgot to include `require 'spec_helper'` in the feature spec. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For anyone who may run into a similar issue in the future, I forgot to include `require 'spec_helper'` in the feature spec (like an idiot).

Comment: and in my case, I had forgotten `require 'capybara/rspec'` in the `spec_helper`... (which your missed line helped remind me to check) ;)

Comment: you can now add `--require spec_helper` to your `.rspec` file and you will no longer need to do the `require` in individual spec files.

Answer (score 12):

In Rails 4, make sure that you have included `'rails_helper'` instead of `'spec_helper'` on top of your specfile:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "Some Feature", :type => :feature do
  ..
end
```

And also make sure that `config.disable_monkey_patching!` is commented out or removed. Otherwise you will encounter problems when running your feature specs.

```
require 'capybara/rspec'    

RSpec.configure do |config|
  ..
  # config.disable_monkey_patching!
  ..
end
```

If you have created a .rspec file inside your project dir, also make sure to to change `spec_helper` to `rails_helper` there as well.

Comment: It's probably cleaner to require `capybara/rspec` by adding it to a file in a `spec/support/`.

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking guard? It sounds like you might need to do `bundle exec guard` to kick things off. It could also be running under the wrong environment (unlikely, but worth a look).